# Question regarding Approval workflows and Selection types

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Sorry if these questions are easy and I'm just being dumb, very new to sharepoint.  For my first question, I set up an approval workflow to follow a user through steps of registration, requiring an approval from someone before they can move on to the next step.  I was able to get that to work, but when I reject an item as I'm testing, it creates another element in my workflow task list, when everything should be done.  I have the approval workflow set to start everytime an element in the list is changed (when a user adds the next step).  This behavior only works on a rejection, and as far as I know, only after the second step.  Is this problem regarding my approval workflow, or could my actual workflow driving the user element be causing it?  Is there a way to test for this?

Finally, my second question is an easy one regarding the menu element.  I have two statements saying that if my current working element was approved, it moves on to the next step, and reverts to the beginning of the step if it was rejected.  I have if statements saying (if [Current Element:ID] is equal to Approved), but it never seems to enter them, even when I check myself that it shows "Approved" in the element list.  Is the smenu type entered as string, or booleans, or what?

Thank you for the help!

Edit:  While I'm at it, does Sharepoint designer 2013 have a "Go to Stage" action?  I swear, I have been looking for it forever now, and it would make my workflow look a lot nicer rather than having multiple loops :)

Comment: I believe I found the answer, but as my rep is still very low (again, new to sharepoint, haha), I will have to wait until the timer is up to post it.  Should anyone see this post and need the answer immediately, make a comment, or message me.  I have my answer saved.

Answer (score 1):

Yay, getting points, making posts!  Since I have enough rep to post to my own answer, I will include it here.

Well, after much digging around, I believe I found the answer for both of my questions.  I will post what I found in case someone else experiences this problem.  For the first question, I wasn't looking at the dates correctly.  When a request is rejected, depending on your approval workflow settings, a new task item will be added to the task list, almost exactly like the one you rejected.  The difference being is that this item has it's due date for approval for the interval you specified while creating the workflow.

As for my second question, the answer is yes, you can reference menu options as their string equivalent. So if you have a menu option that I want to check the status of,  you can just have an equal statement with the string typed in.

I hope this helps anyone else stuck with these problems :)